# frequency table for all columns in pandas

Tags: pandas, multiple-columns, frequency

I want to run frequency table on each of my variable in my df.

```
def frequency_table(x):
    return pd.crosstab(index=x,  columns="count")

for column in df:
    return frequency_table(column)
```

I got an error of 'ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index'

How can i fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: what's your dataframe look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't passing any data. You are just passing a column name.

```
for column in df:
    print(column) # will print column names as strings
```

try

```
ctabs = {}
for column in df:
    ctabs[column]=frequency_table(df[column])
```

then you can look at each crosstab by using the column name as keys in the `ctabs` dictionary

Answer (score 1):

```
for column in df:
    print(data[column].value_counts())
```

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
my_series = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series([1,2,2,3,3,3, "fred", 1.8, 1.8]))
my_series[0].value_counts()
```

will generate output like in below:

```
3       3
1.8     2
2       2
fred    1
1       1
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

Comment: please give some details about your answer.

Comment: output is added